# printing the instance in Python

Tags: python, class, instance, python-idle

class Complex:
        def **init**(self, realpart, imagpart):
            self.real = realpart
            self.imag = imagpart
            print self.real, self.imag

I get this output:

```
>>> Complex(3,2)
3 2
<__main__.Complex instance at 0x01412210>
```

But why does he print the last line?

Comment: I think that's referring to the bundled python ide http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_(Python)

Comment: I hope you understand that this code will just print the two variables, and not the constructor. It's the IDLE that is printing the returned object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because class constructor always return instance, then you could call its method after that

```
inst = Complex(3,2)

inst.dosomething()
```

Answer (score 5):

You running the code from an interactive python prompt, which prints out the result of any statements, unless it is `None`.

Try it:

```
>>> 1
1
>>> 1 + 3
4
>>> "foobar"
'foobar'
>>>
```

So your call to `Complex(3,2)` is creating an object, and python is printing it out.

Answer (score 3):

Because it is the result of the statement "Complex(3,2)".  In other words, a Complex object is being returned, and the interactive interpreter prints the result of the previous statement to the screen.  If you try "c = Complex(3, 2)" you will suppress the message.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to define `__str__(self)` and make it **return** a string representation (not print one).